# How to get real-time data from Firestore database without using Streambuilder()

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch real-time data from Firestore without using `Streambuilder()`.

I did some research and found that  `Streambuilder()` is the only way. Is there any method to fetch data in real time without using Streambuilder()? Please let me know.

Comment: of course you can do that without `StreamBuilder` - you can simply call `Stream.listen` method and rebuild your `StatefulWidget` inside the callback passed to `listen`, but the question is why? `StreamBuilder` is designed for cases like that so why to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to receive the document data through a function and, after some processing, update the UI.

Comment: check `Stream.map` method then - it returns a new `Stream` you can use in `StreamBuilder`

Comment: and i forgot: if your "processing" requires `await something` use `asyncMap`, not `map`

Comment: @pskink Sounds like a perfect answer! Wanna post it below? 

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i'd need to write just few words: it does not deserve for an answer ;-)

Comment: Your first comment explains some key concepts that OP apparently didn't connect. That explanation of using `Stream.listen` and `setState` in a `StatefulWidget` vs a `StreamBuilder` might be exactly what they need too. Having it as an answer makes it more likely that others who are in the same situation find it (plus: it allows us to bring closure to this question).